# event check-in on Form Assembly with Salesforce integration

Tags: formula, integration, connected-apps, campaign, form

Requirements:

- Campaign Members' names on form
- input on form will update the corresponding Campaign Member's status
- compatible with computer and tablet

Would be nice:

- solution can scale and won't take more than 15 minutes or so to implement for each new event
- imported or prefilled data on the form (Campaign Members' names) are dynamic, and don't need to be a static list imported at one time
- doesn't involve custom html coding on TFA side or custom apex on Salesforce side

I figured out one solution using TFA's Salesforce connectors at "Form opened" and "After form submitted" and will post in the answers.

Comment: I don't understand, are you really asking people here to write this for you? What is your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Huh?

Comment: Sorry all, I just came up with this easy to implement check-in system for events that doesn't require apex or downloading an app, and thought others would find it useful.  Not really sure where to post things like that.  I'll delete the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a TFA form with a repeatable section.  The section should have three fields:

1. Text: "Name".  Make this a calculated field and put a space as the formula; it will make the field appear as text/read only.
2. Radio Button: "Status"
3. Text (hidden): "Campaign Member ID"

Build Salesforce (Prefill) connector at "Form opened".  Lookup Campaign ID with custom parameter (you'll have the ID in the url) then map the Campaign ID to a hidden field in your form (not in the repeatable section).  Add Campaign Member as an object dependent on Campaign and have it lookup the Campaign ID from the previous lookup.  For "If more than one records are found" select "Repeat fields (if applicable)".  This allows multiple Campaign Member records to populate in your repeatable section.  Map the Name, Status, and Campaign Member ID fields.

Build Salesforce connector at "After form submitted".  Lookup Campaign ID from that hidden field in your form.  Add Campaign Member as an object dependent on Campaign.  Lookup Campaign Member ID from your repeatable section.  Map the Status field.  For the repeatable option, select "Update a different record for each repeated instance."

In the Notifications section, redirect back to the same form.  Use the Concatenate formula to insert the Campaign ID field back into the url so it redirects back to the same prefilled form.

Bonus: Build a formula field in the Campaign object in Salesforce that automatically generates the prefilled url for each Campaign.

This solution allows us to essentially have a new event check-in form automatically generated each time a new Campaign record is created.  It's worth noting that the form refreshes upon submit faster than the data is updated in Salesforce, so you'll need to refresh the page after 15-30 seconds to get the most up to date prefilled data.